# Сопоставление двух таблиц MySQL особым методом

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы сопоставлены с помощью Join..
нужно сопоставить еще одну, но по столбцу, который изначально нужно отформатировать, то есть, убрать из него все символы, кроме цифр и латинских букв. Такой махинацией он будет похож на тот который будет присоединен...

Возможно ли вообще такое сделать?
[image: Таблицы]

в результате, хотелось бы получить таблицу следующего вида:
[image: Соединенная таблица]

Comment: боюсь вам потребуется много вложенных функций replace каждая из которых удалит один какой нибудь символ и разумеется все удаляемые символы надо будет явно указать

Comment: Я понимаю. Подскажите как правильно написать запрос по этим функциям если знаете

Comment: `replace(replace(art_article_nr,' ',''),'/','')` и т.п.